# Is there any hope of choosing peacefully between Unity and KDE at login time (or session restart time)?

Tags: unity, gnome, kubuntu, kde, display-manager

1. I am almost new to Ubuntu **14.04** (**64** bits, in my case) so I only know the Unity *interface* and a bit of Gnome from previous Ubuntu experience. As the new version of KDE looked promising, I installed *kde-desktop* thinking I would automatically get whatever display manager allowing me to choose between KDE and Unity at boot time.
2. Unfortunately no display manager ever showed up (nor even by clicking on the small icon supposed to do that at login time, which looked dead) and I seemed to be stuck on KDE (very nice, but totally unfamiliar to me, so while I am learning to tune KDE, I just HAVE to go on with my normal work for at least some months with Unity).
3. Reinstalling *ubuntu-desktop* made things even worse : automatic login
   gives me a black screen. Of coures, I can still kill the server from
   a text console and issue a startx, from whick I seem to get Gnome,
   but not Unity :-(

Does somebody know if my system is now hopelessly messed up ? I have a LOT of things which were installed on my system (64 GB on my / SSD, /home is elsewhere) ?

Also is there something somewhere explaining how to make Unity and KDE **coexist** on the system and be *chosen at session start time*, at least until I know them both enough to be able to make an enlightened choice ? I remember it was possible with some former versions of Ubuntu, though KDE did not seem easy enough to master at the time.

Any kdm, lightdm or gdm guru here ? (I tried to reconfigure them and choose one different each time, without any more success). By the way, I had an *autologin* previously and did not know how to remove it. Might that be part of the problem?

Thanks to whoever has or may have a clue. There is clearly something I am not grasping clearly :-/

Comment: Do you completely uninstall kde?

Comment: No, because I would like to be able to keep whatever I customized in KDE (and which is in a .kde or .kde-config, I guess) quietly waiting while I switch back to Unity in a later session for my normal work, in order to (hopefully) resume my discovery of KDE later in a future session.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be easier for you to disable autologin first and then check how you choose different desktops at the login screen.

1. To disable auto login open

   `Settings -> User Accounts`

or in terminal (`ALT`+`CTRL`+`T`) run

```
unity-control-center user-accounts
```

and turn it off

[image]

2. To install KDE run

   `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`
3. `Log out` and choose Desktop

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Steve ! Looks like EXACTLY what I was/am aiming for ! :-)

But unfortunately I have no "Settings" available in my present system state "A": NO Unity vertical bar, NO Gnome horizontal top menu, just my old desktop without controls, plus the ability to issue Alt-Crtl-T to get a terminal. Is there a way to manage from there to remove that autologin or get the "Settings" menu ?

For some unknown reason, I just have a gray graphic screen without anything on it except the mouse pointer when I boot. I have to start a console session (Alt-Ctrl-F1) stop X and issue a startx even to get to "A".

Comment: In case it might help, here is my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf (sorry, new-lines disappear below) :

[SeatDefaults]

autologin-guest=false

autologin-user=fda

autologin-user-timeout=0

autologin-session=lightdm-autologin

greeter-session=unity-greeter

user-session=ubuntu

Comment: Some additional information, just in case : 1) I have both **/tmp** and **/var/log** in a *tmpfs* (because my system is on a SSD) 2) I did install *ubutustudio* and I do not know whether in might interfere

Comment: In terminal try to run `unity-control-center user-accounts`

Comment: Thanks. I got that : fda@S830-256-U14:~$ unity-control-center user-accounts 
ERROR: [/home/fda/.ecryptfs] does not exist
ERROR: Configuration invalid
ERROR: [/home/fda/.ecryptfs] does not exist
ERROR: Configuration invalid
ERROR: [/home/fda/.ecryptfs] does not exist
ERROR: Configuration invalid
ERROR: [/home/fda/.ecryptfs] does not exist
ERROR: Configuration invalid
ERROR: [/home/fda/.ecryptfs] does not exist
ERROR: Configuration invalid
ERROR: [/home/fda/.ecryptfs] does not exist
ERROR: Configuration invalid

but after that the window, and I discovered the autologin was in fact to 0. (!!??)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install unity`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop && 
sudo apt-get install unity`

Comment: « user294557 aka Paganel has only 1 reputation, not yet enough to chat » :-(

Comment: Looks better after I applied your suggestion, Rustlan : now there is a kind of one-text-line width black bar on the top of my screen with the date and some symbols. But still not Unity :-/

Comment: Wait, wait ! When I click "Activities" on the left side of that black bar, Unity appears, after all. However there are no windows "decorations" anywhere allowing me to make the applications windows somewhat smaller. Looks a little like Android ;-)

Comment: Still no welcome and choose user/choose desktop menu after I reboot, though. Still have to lanch "startx" from a text console to get a session.

Comment: Does it look like [Gnome3](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/)?

Comment: Click your name on the top bar, then click the picture next to your name to open the User Accounts window. Turn Automatic Login off.

Comment: I am afraid I never used Gnome 3, so I just cannot say... :-(